# C# Linq how to select all columns except one (DateTime)?

Tags: c#, mysql, list, linq

Let's say I have a project model. This is for an http get request, I'd want to select all the columns in that project model besides one (starting_point) which is a a DateTime. How could I do this? I've seen many threads and somehow I don't understand how I can achieve this? I was hoping just something like this would work

```
_context.interventions.Except(z => z.starting_point).ToList();
```

but it doesn't. At the same time, I'd also like to fetch only the records where the status is "open", but that I know how to do with the following line :

```
var open = _context.project.Where(i => i.status == "open").ToList();
```

The thing is, whenever I tried with except, it wasn't like the lambda for some reason.. I'm also unsure as to how I'd combine the open variable with the query for finding everything that doesn't have a starting_point.. My get request starts like so :

```
public List<Project> Getopen(string status, DateTime starting_point)
```

Any help is appreciated!

TL;DR; I want to select all the projects that don't have a starting_point or an "open" status.

I just tried :

```
var test = _context.projects.Select(i => new { starting_point = i.starting_point }).ToList();
```

and I get an error saying :

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: System.DateTime starting_point>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Project>'
```

Comment: What do you mean by excluding the column?  Do you want it null, default or a new type returned?  This could be done by using `Select` and an anonymous type but I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: I simply don't want that column. I want to return all projects that don't have a starting_point and an open status. I updated the thread!

Comment: Are the tables related?

Comment: It's all in the same table! The status (string) and starting_point (datetime) are both columns from the same Projects table!

Comment: Can u show Projects entity code?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm very new to this. What do you mean by entity code?

Comment: You said, "I don't want that column". This means your resulting rows should not contain the `starting_point` column (regardless of the column value in the database). And then you said, "all projects that don't have a `starting_poing`". This means completely something else: All rows which don't have a value in that column. You should note that all rows of a table *have exactly the same columns*. They only differ in values stored in those columns. Some columns also may have a `NULL` value, which means they are empty.

Comment: Yes I every wrongly formulated my question, the later is the appropriate question. I will edit the question.

Comment: What type would you expect to have returned with a column (field) removed? How do you think the C# compiler could know that? Note: You can't get that error from the line you posted - what code actually cause the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No create an object anonymous. Your method return a list of Project.

```
var open = _context.project
                     .Where(i => i.status == "open" && i.starting_point == null)
                     .ToList();
```

Your Datetime should are nullable: `DateTime?`

Comment: Thank you, done! Though now I wonder... Why is it that this time I could check the answer as accepted, but other times it says to wait like 1-2 days or something? Strange.. Nonetheless, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Select` and an anonymous type:

```
var open = _context.project
    .Where(i => i.status == "open" && i.starting_point == null)
    .Select(i => new { Status = i.status})
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I had tried something very similar a few minutes ago and I get the same error as what you just proposed. I showed the error in an edit of the question! Except from what I can see with your code I get cannot convert type string Status to list Project

Comment: Change your `Getopen` method to have return type `List<object>`